# How to convert FORMAT '--(37)9' from Teradata to Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, teradata, azure-synapse

I have the following query with me:

```
SELECT T1.C1,
CAST((SUM(1) OVER (ORDER BY T1.C2 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) + T2.C3 (FORMAT '--(37)9') AS VARCHAR(20) )) AS RESULT
FROM
T1
CROSS JOIN
T2;
```

What would be the equivalent for (FORMAT '--(37)9') in Azure Synapse Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really weird query (including `SUM(1)` instead of `COUNT(*)`)

It's returning an integer as a left aligned string.

Unless T2.C3 is a decimal with fractional digits you can simply remove the FORMAT and CAST to VARCHAR(20).

If T2.C3 has a fraction, CAST to BIGINT or DECIMAL(38,0) first.